# Big Sur react native how to get watchman to run?

Tags: macos, react-native, macos-big-sur, watchman

I am trying to run a react native project but I keep getting:

> Watchman:  watchman --no-pretty get-sockname returned with exit code=1, signal=null, stderr= 2020-12-20T01:04:27,184: [0x118044e00] the owner of /usr/local/var/run/watchman/mattroberts-state is uid 0 and doesn't match your euid 501

I think it is a permission problem but I don't know how to fix it.  Does anyone know what is wrong and how to fix it?

If I could get the uid to match the euid, it seems it should be fixed, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 1):

> If I could get the uid to match the euid, it seems it should be fixed, but I don't know how.

Looks like the owner of the watchman state directory is set to root. You can fix it by running:

```
sudo chown -R "$(whoami)" "/usr/local/var/run/watchman/$(whoami)-state"
```

Answer (score 0):

While I was unable to fix Watchman, after uninstalling it the React Native app runs.  I don't think it will automatically reload, but you can still cause a reload to occur with command r in the simulator.

Since I had installed Watchman with homebrew,
I uninstalled it with

```
brew uninstall Watchman
```

in the terminal

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me
`sudo chmod 0700 /usr/local/var/run/watchman/$(whoami)-state`

Comment: Why do you prefer this over some of the other suggestions offered?